# Merge Two Measures Into A Single Column using Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

Hi,
I have two different score for list of products i want to merge them in a single column using Dax as they are in measure. I guess concatenate will not work as they are measures, will switch statement will work?
Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean they are "measures"? Do you mean a float (i.e. 5.0)?

Comment: Its a DAX Measure, two separate measure , i need to combine them in one Column so i can use them for calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
COALESCE([Measure1], [Measure2])
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but i am still using older version of Power BI desktop due to some work policy. so COALESCE([Measure1], [Measure2]) will not work for me.

Comment: Just create your own coalesce then. It is shorthand for if(isblank([Measure1]),[Measure2], [Measure1])